# Is it possible to set Chart options through the Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I am able to update a "stacked area chart", however I cannot figure out how to set "Treat labels as text" on the Horizontal axis.  (This is done in the UI by clicking "Edit Chart -> Customize -> Horizontal axis -> Treat labels as text")

Does anyone know a way to do this with Sheets API?  Is there another way?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to set `Treat labels as text` of the chart in the Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the property for setting `Treat labels as text` in the request body. And I prepare 2 patterns of the checked `Treat labels as text` and the unchecked `Treat labels as text`, and when both patterns are compared with the chart object retrieved with the method of spreadsheets.get, I could find no differences for both. By this, I thought that in the current stage, there is no method for setting `Treat labels as text` in Sheets API.

So as one of several workarounds, here, I would like to propose to use Web Apps as an API. When Google Apps Script is used, `Treat labels as text` can be set. This workaround uses this.

### Usage:

The usage of this workaround is as follows.

#### 1. Create new project of Google Apps Script.

Sample script of Web Apps is a Google Apps Script. So please create a project of Google Apps Script.

If you want to directly create it, please access to https://script.new/. In this case, if you are not logged in Google, the log in screen is opened. So please log in to Google. By this, the script editor of Google Apps Script is opened.

#### 2. Copy and paste script.

Please copy and paste the following script.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var spreadsheetId = e.parameter.spreadsheetId;
  var chartId = e.parameter.chartId;
  var treatLabelsAsText = e.parameter.treatLabelsAsText;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var done = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var charts = sheets[i].getCharts();
    if (charts.length > 0) {
      for (var j = 0; j < charts.length; j++) {
        if (charts[j].getChartId() == chartId) {
          var modifiedChart = charts[j].modify().setOption('treatLabelsAsText', treatLabelsAsText).build();
          sheets[i].updateChart(modifiedChart);
          done = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (done) break;
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");
}
```

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.

   - This setting is for testing this workaround.
   - When "Only myself" is set to "Who has access to the app:", the access token is required to be used.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### 4. Sample curl.

In order to test to access to the Web Apps, please use the following curl command.

```
curl -GL \
  -d "spreadsheetId=###" \
  -d "chartId=###" \
  -d "treatLabelsAsText=true" \
  "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
```

If you deployed Web Apps as "Only myself" for "Who has access to the app:", please use your access token as follows.

```
curl -GL \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ###" \
  -d "spreadsheetId=###" \
  -d "chartId=###" \
  -d "treatLabelsAsText=true" \
  "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
```

- Please set the URL of Web Apps retrieved above and the Spreadsheet ID, the chart ID and the value of `treatLabelsAsText`.
- When above curl command is run, "Treat labels as text" is checked of the specific chart in the Spreadsheet. And you can see `Done.` at the console.

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- When you want to use the access token, please include the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` and/or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to the access token.

### References:

- [modify()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#modify)
- [setOption()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setoptionoption,-value)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.